# Linux Mint 18 installed on Intel NUC then moved SSD to different NUC where it fails to boot from SSD

Tags: linux, linux-mint, intel

Linux Mint 18 was installed on an Intel NUC5i7RYH computer. That PC has a hardware problem so I moved the Samsung EVO 960 SSD to a new NUC7i7BNK, but the second NUC does not boot from the EVO SSD. It does see it in the BIOS as a boot device, and I can boot from an Live USB Flash Drive with Linux Mint installed. How can I boot the second NUC from the EVO SSD?

Comment: old nuc Nuc5i7RYH to new nuc NUC7i7BNK

Comment: this fixed my problem  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

boot-repair

Comment: So, you added boot-repair from its PPA https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair, ran `sudo apt-get update`, installed boot-repair, and then ran `boot-repair` so it would boot with an i7 CPU. Sounds like you could turn that into an answer other folks could use. Comments can't format as well as a Question or Answer, as you see above; make sure to add two spaces after the end of each line to force a newline for formatting purposes when creating an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my problem. I installed and ran `boot-repair`.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair 
boot-repair
```